# Exception handling in Web API Controller and throwing custom error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, exception, soa

For one of my project I am using Web API with sort of SOA architecture.In the Controller I wants to catch the exception ( thrown by Repository) and return `HttpResposeMessage`.
What I want is there should be a BaseController which inherit ApiController (`class BaseController : ApiController`) and each of my Controller should be inherited by baseController 
e.g. `class TaskController : BaseController` and if any exception occur in my controller then it should be handled by `BaseController`.
Demo :

Following are the projects in our VS Solution :(Project structure)

```
XYZ.Model
XYZ.Repository
XYZ.WebServices
XYZ.Exception
XYZ.UI
```

Code :
XYZ.Model

```
public class Error
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

}
```

XYZ.Exception

```
// To create the custom exception as per our need
public class BaseException : Exception
{
    private Error _error;
    public Error Error
    {
        get { return _error; }
    }

    public BaseException()
    {
        _error = new Error();
    }

    public void SetErrorCode(string code)
    {
        _error.Code = code;
    }

    public void SetErrorMessage(string message)
    {
        _error.Message = message;
    }
}


public class TaskNotFoundException : BaseException
{
    public TaskNotFoundException()
    {
        string errorCode = "T0001";
        base.SetErrorCode(errorCode);
        base.SetErrorMessage((new ExceptionMessage()).GetExceptionMessage(errorCode));
    }
}
```

XYZ.Repository

```
public Task UpdateTaskDetails(Task task)
{
    try
    {
        //--Task updating logic--//
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new TaskUpdateFailedException();
    }
    return task;
}
```

XYZ.WebServices

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateResponseMessage()
    {
        try
        {
            GetTasksByUserIdAndProjectId(new TaskQuery());
        }
        catch(BaseException exception)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, exception.Error);
        }
    }

    public virtual  List<Task> GetTasksByUserIdAndProjectId(TaskQuery query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I can be overridden");
    }
}


public class TaskController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public override List<Task> GetTasksByUserIdAndProjectId(TaskQuery query)
    {
        return _taskRepo.GetTasksByUserIdAndProjectId(query.UserId, query.ProjectId);
    }

}
```

In `TaskController` if any exception occur in `GetTasksByUserIdAndProjectId` method it should throw the exception to the `BaseController CreateReponseMessage()` and there it will return the `HttpResponseMessage` to the client.
Note : In each Controller there are multiple Get/Put/Post method, so it is not possible to declare all the methods(web Service methods) in `BaseController` to catch the exception of child class in current structure of my project.

Is there any better way to handle Exception in Web API that easily get fitted in my project?

Comment: This can be better done using an exception filter.

Comment: @Nkosi, Thanks for your suggestion, I've implemented exception filter and it's working fine. But I have one more question " Can we handle some Validation failure error kind of things in exception filter? AS Validation failure is not exception but I want it to be handled in a common class."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use an exception filter like this:

First we create our own exception:

```
public class UserFriendlyException: Exception
    {
        public UserFriendlyException(string message) : base(message) { }
        public UserFriendlyException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }
    }
```

Then we create a filter:

```
public class UserFriendlyExceptionFilterAttribute: ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            var friendlyException = context.Exception as UserFriendlyException;
            if (friendlyException != null)
            {
                context.Response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new {Message = friendlyException.Message}); 
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally in the config for WebApi we add that filter.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            ...


            config.Filters.Add(new UserFriendlyExceptionFilterAttribute());

            ...
        }
    }
```

With this solution you can throw UserFriendlyException anywhere in the code and the response will be according to the filter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've implemented exception filter and it's working fine. But I have one more question " Can we handle some Validation failure error kind of things in exception filter? AS Validation failure is not exception but I want it to be handled in a common class.".